# I am trying to figure out url syntax to pass parameters to my "Sikuli Server"

Tags: java, jetty, sikuli

enix12enix has written a standalone sikuli server to remotely initiate sikuli scripts.  I have the server running and I'm now trying to pass values along with the url.  I imagine it will look something like this :

```
http://server:9000/test.do?script=/yourscript&argv[1]=arg1value
```

Everything before the & works properly as it stands.  I know the answer is somewhere in the java found here:

```
https://github.com/enix12enix/sikuliserver/blob/master/java/src/org/sikuli/SikuliScriptParamProcessor.java
```

As there is a function called extractparameters. Can anyone help figure out the syntax for the url?

Thanks a lot,

Jacob

Comment: It looks like there is an external reference to a class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest with function getParameterNames()

Comment: pretty sure the format is something like:
    http://server:9000/test.do?script=/yourscript&argv1=arg1value

The regex (in the java) explains the formatting.

now to figure out how to pass it to the sikuli script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the pattern that's used to check if the name of the params are correct, you should send the params with this format: `argv## (1-99)`. So instead of sending `argv[1]` in the url you should be `argv1`.

Comment: THanks Jair I figured out how to reference within the Sikuli script as well.

Normally, while running a script from the command line (--args value1 value2) , you would reference the argument within the script like this:
    import sys
    var1 = sys.argv[1]
    var2 = sys.argv[2]

Comment: That's right, but in order to send it through the URL did it work as I suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Jair, I figured out how to reference this within the Sikuli script as well. I imagine that those familiar with Java / Python / Jython are already aware of this, but I am just a noob setting up a remote Sikuli server.

Parameters can be passed through the url as follows:

```
http://server:9000/test.do?script=/yourScriptName.sikuli&argv1=value1&argv2=value2
```

and so on, through argv99.

Normally, while running a script from the command line (--args value1 value2) , you would reference the argument within the Sikuli script like this:

```
import sys
var1 = sys.argv[1]
var2 = sys.argv[2]
```

While working with the java side of things, the reference is a little different:

```
import java
var1 = java.lang.System.getProperty('argv1')
var2 = java.lang.System.getProperty('argv2')
```

And so on.